# Why is there a KeyError when the dictionary has the key?

Tags: python

I am creating a simple flask application to store JSON files and read them. The application should return a JSON file I made as a test. Here's the url: http://IP:5000/?room=test&game=test. I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/python/universalgameserver.py", line 10, in api_set
    return json.loads(readJSON(request.args['room'], request.args['game']))
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/python/universalgameserver.py", line 17, in readJSON
    f = open("~/saves/${room}_${game}.json".format(room, game), "r")
KeyError: 'room'
```

Printing out the dictionary, it looks like this:
`{'room': 'test', 'game': 'test'}`
My code looks like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def api_set():
    if request.method == "POST":
        writeJSON(request.form['room'], request.form['game'], request.form['json'])
    else:
        print(dict(request.args))
        return json.loads(readJSON(request.args['room'], request.args['game']))

def writeJSON(room, game, json):
    f = open("~/saves/${room}_${game}.json".format(room, game), "w")
    f.write(json)
    f.close()
def readJSON(room, game):
    f = open("~/saves/${room}_${game}.json".format(room, game), "r")
    contents = f.read()
    f.close()
    return contents
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.0.36')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `KeyError` is raised in `readJSON` during the formatting of:

```
f = open("~/saves/${room}_${game}.json".format(room, game), "r")
```

Change it to:

If in Python 2:

```
f = open("~/saves/{0}_{1}.json".format(room, game), "r")
```

If in Python 3.6 or newer, using f-string which allows you to easy format:

```
f = open(f"~/saves/{room}_{game}.json", "r")
```

And it shall work like magic!

P.S.

Similarly, change in the `writeJSON` too.

Comment: Or, with new enough Pythons, `open(f"~/saves/{room}_{game}.json")` :)

Comment: Sure ;) guessed that if he used `format` it's Python 2 in the first place. Anyway, I'll add that, thank you @AKX :)